# Вопрос по UPDATE запросу

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть две таблицы `deposit` и `info`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в таблице `info` хранится общий баланс.

в таблице `deposit` хранятся "купленные акции", для любого пользователя может быть несколько "акций".

такой запрос:

```
SET @dayproc :=7 ;
SET @day : =0;

UPDATE deposit d, info i
SET d.earn = d.earn + @day:= @day+d.sum * @dayproc/100,
  i.balance = i.balance + @day
WHERE i.uid = d.uid;
```

я предполагал, что  для каждой строки в таблице `deposit`, будет считаться дневной процент, и прибавляться к балансу в `info`, но в итоге к балансу прибавляется только процент за первую акцию.

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: *d.earn = d.earn + @day:= @day+d.sum * @dayproc/100* — а это вообще валидная конструкция? я про `:=` в середине оператора присвоения.

Comment: вы можете изложить словами, что именно вам нужно вычислить? из приведённого кода это как-то не очевидно. без "депозитов", "купленных акций", "балансов", "дневных процентов" и т.п. терминов предметной области.

Answer (score 1):

не дождавшись ответа на вопросы, пробую угадать, что же вам нужно:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3a07/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table i (id int, balance float);

create table d (id int, earn float, sum float);

insert into i values
  (1, 1000),
  (2, 2000);

insert into d values
  (1, 100, 10),
  (1, 200, 20),
  (2, 300, 30),
  (2, 400, 40);

update i
join (
  select id, sum(sum * 7/100) as sum
  from d
  group by id
) as d1
  on d1.id = i.id
set i.balance = i.balance + d1.sum;

update d
set d.earn = d.earn + d.sum * 7/100;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from i
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3a07/1/0)**:

```
| id | balance |
|----|---------|
|  1 |  1002.1 |
|  2 |  2004.9 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select * from d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3a07/1/1)**:

```
| id |  earn | sum |
|----|-------|-----|
|  1 | 100.7 |  10 |
|  1 | 201.4 |  20 |
|  2 | 302.1 |  30 |
|  2 | 402.8 |  40 |
```